# How do I call a method of one class from another class?

Tags: java, class, methods

I have a method `public boolean validDate (int day, int month, int year)` which does the following:

> The month can only be in the range 1-12 and a month must have the correct number of days eg 30.2.1997 is invalid because February can only have 28 days, or 29 days if the year is a leap year and this method must return true if the date is valid and false if the date is invalid.

This method is in a class called `ValidDate`. And I need to call it from another class. How would I go by doing this? I added an image of what I have so far which is probably wrong.

[image]

Comment: Post the code directly in the question instead of an image of it.

Comment: Basically you need to create an instance of `ValidDate` and then call the `validDate()` method on it.

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: [Classes and Objects](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html) lesson from Oracle's Java tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
public static boolean validate(int year, int month, int day){
        if(year < 0 || month < 0 || day < 0){
            return false;
        }
        YearMonth yearMonth = YearMonth.of(year, month);
        int days = yearMonth.lengthOfMonth();
        return day <= days;
    }
```

Comment: thank you but do you need static i dont think i can have it as static is there any other way

Comment: there is not context related to this method, if you write is as public static, you can use it anywhere without create an object first.